# Isn't energy absolute according to Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I was taught that Internal Energy $U$ is  a relative quantity: only changes in $U$ are meaningful. It doesn't have an absolute value, since it always comes with an arbitrary constant (for example $U = nT +c$).

Entropy $S$, on the other hand, has an absolute value thanks to the Third Postulate of Thermodynamics. Volume $V$ and number of moles $n$ are also absolute, obviously.

The Fundamental Relation of a system relates $S$, $U$, $V$ and $n$ (For example $U = e^{S/n}Vn$, but any example would work).

Since $S$, $V$, and $n$ are always absolute quantities, doesn't that mean that $U$ must also be absolute? So any system has a meaningful, absolute value of $U$ with no arbitrary constant?

Comment: If you offset $U$ by a constant, say $c$, then you simply add it to your fundamental relation. So your example would become $U = e^{S/n}Vn +c$

Comment: In introductory physics we usually see $U=mgh$, does this mean $U$ is absolute there also?

Comment: The problem is which equation you use to tie $U$ directly to $S,V,N$ as the first principle is only about differentials.

Comment: > *"Entropy S, on the other hand, has an absolute value thanks to the Third Postulate of Thermodynamics."* Third law only states that changes of entropy are zero when $T\to 0$. Citation for the "absolute value"?

Comment: @JánLalinský "Postulate IV. The entropy of any system vanishes in the state where T->0" from Callen's Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics. So $S = 0$ absolutely at that state...

Comment: @JuanPerez IV postulate by Callen was already put in the most convenient form to have a conic domain of S (see my answer). However, from the point of view of the underlying physics, it could equally well be stated as "the entropy of any system goes to a constant independent of the state, phase and other thermodynamic variables in the state where T->0".

Comment: That is Callen's definition for the purpose of his exposition. It is not universally required for $S$ to vanish at $T\to 0$. For example, in statistical physics it makes sense to define $S$ as log of compatible states, and that may be non-zero even for $T=0$ (due to degeneracy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that the temperature $T$, entropy $S$, pressure $P$, volume $V$ and amount of material $N$ are all amenable to being modeled as absolute. However, thermodynamics formulates the complete expression for internal energy as

$$U=TS - PV + \sum \mu N.$$

This shifts the relative nature to the chemical potential $\mu$, which—like the internal energy $U$—can be measured relative to a reference only. (The same holds for the enthalpy $H\equiv U+PV$, the Helmholtz potential $F\equiv U-TS$, and the Gibbs free energy $G\equiv U+PV-TS$, and after all, the chemical potential $\mu\equiv\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\right)_{T,P}$ is just the molar Gibbs free energy.) If you consider a closed system at equilibrium so that the last term is constant, then you’re implicitly taking that system as the reference.

Comment: Thank you. If *that* is the fundamental relation, then I agree that U won't be absolute. But I asked because Callen's *"Postulate II: There exists a function called the entropy, S, of the extensive parameters (U,V,n,etc) of any composite system, defined for all equilibrium states [...]"* seems to say the fundamental relation is not a differential, it's just $S=S(U,V,n)$

Comment: Callen writes in Chapter 1: "*[$S=S(U,V,N_i)$] and [$U=U(S,V,N_i)$] are alternative forms of the fundamental relation, and each contains* all *thermodynamic information about the system.*" The version I write is $U=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N_i}S+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N_i}V+\sum_i\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i}\right)_{S,V}N_i$ for a system that accepts heating, mechanical work, and mass transfer.

Answer (score 13):

Energy and entropy are not directly measurable. Only *differences* may be measured. It is enough to think about typical energy measurements via work and heat measurements (always referring to an initial and a final state).

The third principle of thermodynamics only states that the limit of the entropy for temperature going to absolute zero is a constant independent of the material and other thermodynamic variables. Then, due to the arbitrariness of the constant (only differences are measurable), it is convenient to take it equal to zero (this final step was taken by Planck, who explicitly wrote, "*It is easy to see that since the value of the entropy contains an arbitrary additive constant, that, without loss of generality,
we may write $\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}S(T) = 0$.*  M.Planck, Treatise on Thermodynamics).

In essence, the real content of the third principle is that entropy is bounded below. This fact strictly parallels the similar property for the energy of any thermodynamical system. The exact value of such a lower limit can be conventionally fixed to any value since has no measurable consequence. The most convenient choice is zero.

I have to say that the *convenience* of bounding from below energy and entropy with zero is usually underestimated in the classical presentations of thermodynamics. Actually, it simplifies many statements that would become unduly complicated if the range of values of the entropy $S$ and internal energy $U$ would not start from zero. It is enough to think how simple it is to state the condition of homogeneity of degree one (extensiveness) of $S$ (or $U$) as a function of its extensive variables:
$$
S(\lambda U, \lambda V, \lambda N) = \lambda S(U,V,N)
$$
**for every $U$, $V$, $N$, and $\lambda$ greater than zero.**
Here, the domain of $S(U,V,N)$ can be taken as the cone $U>0, V>0$, and $N>0$. If we would not take the minimum of $U$ as zero, a value $\lambda>1$ could bring a value of energy close to the minimum out of the original domain of $S$. Of course, we could restate the condition more carefully, but at the price of a more complex statement.

Statistical mechanics could induce us to think that the value of the entropy is absolute. However, it is again only a matter of convention. It is pretty clear in the case of classical statistical mechanics, where the *counting* of the microstates is possible only by introducing a constant $h$, with the dimension of an action, whose value is arbitrary since it modifies the value of the entropy only by a universal constant. Quantum Statistical Mechanics seems to establish an absolute value of the entropy. However, in this case, too, one quickly recognizes that the identification of the statistical formula for the logarithm of the number of microstates with the physical entropy requires integrating the relation
$$
\frac{1}{k_BT} = \frac{\partial \log \Omega}{\partial E}
$$
resulting once again in an arbitrary constant.

Comment: This is completely new to me, all my books always clarified that S had an absolute value. I was sure statistical mechanics proved it, but your comment on an arbitrary h is interesting (I never paid much attention on how we rigorously count microstates, I'll have to read about it). I was convinced S was absolute. Guess I was wrong?

Comment: @JuanPerez Actually, this is a point rarely made in the elementary textbook, where the discussion about the third principle is usually short. But the founding fathers of Thermodynamics had it very clear in mind.